# identifying deleted columns

Tags: sql-server-2005

i am using sql server 2000 .I have a table with four columns ie. col1,col2,col3 and col4.
I have records in the table .
I used dbcc page command and i could see the values of all the column.
I then deleted a column , col2, from the table and did dbcc page again.
I could see the values of all the columns except for col2 which value "Dropped" (The record structure was still the same).
I understand that the column information are stored in "syscolumn" table
However the record for col2 was not found(for obvious reason).
I am wondering in which system table can i find the information the col2 is deleted.
Where is this information stored?

Thanks,
Jude

Comment: heres the dump of the record using dbcc command.

00000000: 10001800 01000000 02000000 03000000 †................
00000010: 04000000 05000000 0500e0†††††††††††††...........

Slot 0 Column 0 Offset 0x4 Length 4

Col1 = 1

Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0x8 Length 4

DROPPED = 2

Slot 0 Column 2 Offset 0xc Length 4

Col3 = 3

Slot 0 Column 3 Offset 0x10 Length 4

Col4 = 4

Slot 0 Column 4 Offset 0x14 Length 4

Col5 = 5


here as you can see,col2 is marked as "dropped"
There as to be a place where the information that col2 is deleted is stored.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only answer for 2005, although that might give you enough of an indication for 2000. The information is not available as far as I am aware via DMV's, to get at the information you would need to use the Dedicated Admin Console (DAC).

Using the DAC connection the tables columns can be found in sys.sysrowsetsolumns - if you filter that down to the individual rowsetid / hobtid of the object you can see your columns and there are two fields to note, status and rowsetcolid.

As a test case, I output the value of the query twice, before and after dropping the column.

```
  select * from sys.sysrowsetcolumns where rowsetid = 72057594038845440
  ALTER TABLE dbo.foo DROP COLUMN test2
  select * from sys.sysrowsetcolumns where rowsetid = 72057594038845440
```

Output was

```
rowsetid           rowsetcolid hobtcolid status rcmodified maxinrowlen
72057594038845440  1           1           0        0      4
72057594038845440  2           2           0        0      4
72057594038845440  3           3           0        0      4
72057594038845440  4           4           0        0      4

rowsetid           rowsetcolid hobtcolid status rcmodified maxinrowlen
72057594038845440  1           1           0        0      4
72057594038845440  2           2           0        0      4
72057594038845440  4           4           0        0      4
72057594038845440  65536       3           2        0      4
```

The test was dropping column 3 and you can see hobtcolid 3 has altered the status to 2 and the rowsetcolid has been set to 65536. What the status and id mean I can only infer from the actions taken.

Addendum : Do not edit any data in the system tables via the DAC - very very risky.

Comment: thanks for the very useful information!
I have one more query.How would i identify whether the deleted column
is a variable length column like varchar

Comment: Hi andrew, I found this information in syshobtcolumns system table.

Thanks for all your help!
Cheer!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to identify which column was deleted.
is hobtcolid always = rowsetcolid.

Comment: I'll have a look at it tonight on a test databse, the hobtcolid should be able to link to syshobtcolumns but I'll need to check. The rowsetcolid clearly gets mashed as a result of the deletion so is of no use.

Comment: I can link the hobtcolid to the sys.syscolumns.colid, but once the col is deleted, the entry in sys.syscolumns goes with it. Rowsetcolumsn records the deletion still, but without the details about the column remaining in sys.syscolumns I do not believe I can get to the deleted column name, I just can see what ordinal position it used to have.

Comment: thanks for replying,
  I have come across a situation in my database where the hobtcolid is not equal to colid. Can u let me know when this situation can come up?
Thanks,
Jude